# Incorrect Output for List

Tags: java, list, output

I'm doing a beginner Java tutorial on Lists, and am presented with the below problem

```
// 1) Declare am ArrayList of strings
// 2) Call the add method and add 10 random strings
// 3) Iterate through all the elements in the ArrayList
// 4) Remove the first and last element of the ArrayList
// 5) Iterate through all the elements in the ArrayList, again.
```

Below is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ex1_BasicArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
            Random rand = new Random();
            String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
            String randy = sb.toString();
            list.add(randy);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <  list.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(list.get(i));
        }   
        list.remove(0);
        list.remove(list.size()-1);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I have managed to generate an output, but it is incorrect :(

For my first `System.out.print(list.get(i));` I'm trying to get an output for 10 String values, but I get 12.

Sample output: `nhgacqhlejph`

And when I run the second `System.out.println(list.get(i));`, I get an output for 8 String Values, which is correct if I started out with 10 in the list, but I have 12, so it means that 4 values were removed :/

Sample output:

```
g
a
c
q
h
l
e
j
```

Does anyone know where I went wrong with my code?

To repeat:

1. I wish to get 10 String values of one letter each from the first `System.out.print(list.get(i));`
2. I also want to get 2 less String values from the original list by running the second `System.out.println(list.get(i));`

Comment: 'int i = 0; i <= 10; i++' will generate 11 elements

Comment: Your first `for` loops from `i = 0` to `i = 10`, there you get a 11 length string, but i dont know where the 12 char comes from.

Comment: A good way to debug is to get rid of the randomness. Instead of a random string (hard to debug) put the number as a string list.add(i + "");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the `for` loop should stop at `i=9` not at `i=10`. Hence the loop should be as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
```

Second, when printing the list after removing the first and last elements, you're not printing a new line to distinguish between the two outputs. You can add a `println` between them so that they are separated:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  list.size(); i++){
    System.out.print(list.get(i));
}   
System.out.println();
list.remove(0);
list.remove(list.size()-1);
```

Having said this, your implementation is not very efficient in that it creates a `StringBuilder` in every iteration of the loop as well as a `Random` object. You can create only one `Random` object to use it for every iteration. You also don't need a `StringBuilder` to begin with. The program can be simplified to the following, for example:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Random rand = new Random();
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    list.add(String.valueOf(alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(alphabet.length()))));
}
```

Comment: Just a small question, what does `+ ""`do in your last line? Does it convert the new addition to the list into a String? I thought one would use the toString() method for that?

Comment: @KennethYong Yes concatenating with `""` generates a `String`. Or you can use `String.valueOf(char)` (see updated answer) which is better since the former method uses a `StringBuilder` behind the scenes. `toString` is a method that belongs to types that extend `Object` which you can use to print a string representation of your object. But it is not available on primitive types like `char`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: `int i = 0; i <= 10; i++` generates 11 chars.
First loop will produce 11 characters (without newline).
Second loop will produce 9 characters (with newlines).

Therefore you see 12 characters (11 from 1st loop + one from the 2nd) in one line and then 8 characters on next lines

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
```

Above for lop runs from 0 till 10 both including (so it runs for 11 times) apart from this your code looks fine. change **i<=10** to **i<10**

**I had rewritten the program and you could use this for your testing**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ex1_BasicArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            Random rand = new Random();
            String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
            String randy = sb.toString();
            list.add(randy);
        }

        printList(list);  

        // Remove Elements
        list.remove(0);
        list.remove(list.size()-1);

        printList(list);
    }

    /**
     * @param list
     */
    private static void printList(List<String> list) {
        System.out.println("List size:"+list.size());
        System.out.println("List="+list);
        for(String listElement: list){
            System.out.println(listElement);
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the program is

```
List size:10
List=[k, g, i, a, g, k, s, s, x, t]
k
g
i
a
g
k
s
s
x
t
List size:8
List=[g, i, a, g, k, s, s, x]
g
i
a
g
k
s
s
x
```

**Note**
List entries would vary as they are picked randomly, but size would be 10 & 8 before delete & after delete respectively